# API is not working Android Kotlin retrofit API for Mobile recharge

Tags: rest, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

There is a API which running in post request. this code is not working:

**PHP API query:**

```
query('select mt.translationID,mt.mobile,mt.amount, mt.operatorCodeTimestamp as rechargedate, mt.status from mst_translation mt join agent_users mu on mu.agent_id=mt.userID where mu.mobile="'.$userID.'" and mu.domainName="'.$domain.'"')->result();

interface ApiEndPoint {

    @POST("api/Recharge/make")
    fun rechargeMobile(
        @Query("userId") userId: String,
        @Query("domain") domain: String,
        @Body request: RechargeRequest
    ): Call<RechargeResponce?>?

}
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MoneyTransfer : AppCompatActivity() {

    val binding by lazy{
        ActivityMoneyTransferBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }
    private lateinit var apiEndPoint : ApiEndPoint
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initBlock()

        binding.proceed.setOnClickListener {
            dataSetup()
        }


    }

    fun dataSetup(){

        val mobileRechargeRequest = RechargeRequest(
            operatorCode = binding.operatorCode.text.toString(),
            userID = "2050",
            userpin = "1234",
            amount = binding.mobileNumber.text.toString(),
            servicenumber = binding.mobileNumber.text.toString(),
            domain = "www.pay2kart.com",
            servicetype = "MOBILE"
        )
// Create a RechargeRequest object with the user ID and amount

// Make the API call
        val response = apiEndPoint.rechargeMobile("2050", "www.pay2kart.com",mobileRechargeRequest)

// Handle the response
        response!!.enqueue(object : Callback<RechargeResponce?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<RechargeResponce?>,
                response: Response<RechargeResponce?>
            ) {

                try {

                    if (response != null) {

                        Log.e("message", response.message().toString())

                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@MoneyTransfer,
                            response.message().toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MoneyTransfer,
                        "Some NetWork Error Has been found ... ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RechargeResponce?>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MoneyTransfer, "Failed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }


        })
    }

    private fun initBlock() {
        var retrofit = ServerConnection.getConnection()
        if (retrofit != null) {

            apiEndPoint = retrofit.create(ApiEndPoint::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**Api**

```
https://www.pay2kart.com/pay2kart_api_testing/Services/index.php/api/Recharge/make
```

In postman when I test the API and when I put data in body row file then this API show success message:

```
{
"operatorCode":"102",
"userID":"2050",
"userpin":"1234",
"servicenumber":"8878840990", 
"domain":"www.pay2kart.com",
"servicetype":"MOBILE"
}
```

I am new in programming where I am making mistake.

I am trying to put some data into this API and call the API for mobile recharge.

Comment: "this code is not working" is extremely vague, can you be more specific about what's not working? Does the server return a response? Is the application crashing?

Comment: toast shows a message forbidden

Comment: It seems that your server might be returning the [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) error code - you'd need to figure out why that happens.

Comment: zoom call or whatsapp call